# Error reading Disk while merging partitions

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

I had around a 500 MB of unallocated space in my HDD so I decided to marge it with C: drive. I used [AOMEI partition toolkit.](http://www.disk-partition.com/download-home.html)

I did a trial run by splitting my D: drive into two (unallocated one of the partitions) and joined them. This is similar to the scenario with C: drive and some unallocated space. The software said restart the computer and the partition will be allocated in a pre OS mode(Same thing happened with D drive) and it did. Midway through the merging it showed an error occurred and restarted. From that time it is showing

"DISK READ ERROR OCCURRED press ctrl+alt+del to restart" and it goes on in a loop.

I installed [MiniTool Partition wizard](https://www.partitionwizard.com/) so that I could allocate the drive spaces without booting into the OS but it is showing

"USB descriptor file not found" for my mouse(not recognizing it)and not going inside the main partition screen.

I just want to boot into my win 10...How can I do that??Is there any recovery software that I can try or any cmd code that will help me recover my OS?????

Please help me fix this   problem....

Comment: Just wipe it & restore from backup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NEVER MERGE that unpartitioned space (in most cases, there will be shown `500 mb`).
 It is kept by system for special cases, and you should not use that space for your needs. 
At first, try to re-attach that space again and leave it as unallocated space. Then see if system boots.

Comment: actually there was a separate partition named `Recovery` so I thought this was just used for nothing and I tried to merge it. Anyway I now have ubuntu up and running in my PC(Different drive. C drive is still the same as it was before). Is there anyway by which I can recover the windows  data in this OS???